# The Solution of Duplicate Rank doesn't Work on Excel

Tags: excel, duplicates, rank

The rank 25 doesn't work as it should be. Please help.

I use below formula to do rank on Ms. Excel.

=RANK(H7,$H$7:$H$56,0)+COUNTIF($H$7:H7,H7)-1

And below is the data on my table. The total is 32 rows.

[image]

Comment: You have 150 in two cells, `H7` and `H32` respectively where rank is being returned as 25 and 26. This appears to be inline with the rest of duplicates. What is the issue?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij The formula should return 25 and 26, but here it's return as 26 and 26.

Comment: Strange, it is returning correct results for me. Please recheck on a fresh sheet and see if it works for you.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij After refreshing for 2 hours, I just realized I have the same issue. This 25 26 even if they have the total 150, but actually another 150 is an accumulation from some decimal amount. I need to fix it. Can you help which FORMULA apart from ROUND that I can use?

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij I use ROUNDDOWN and it works now. Thanks. Case closed.

Comment: Great, as I see it I had no chance of knowing it. I simply used data from the snapshot to test build the case.

Answer (score 0):

With Microsoft-365, give a try to the following formula-

```
=MAP(A1:A32,
LAMBDA(x,
CHOOSEROWS(FILTER(SEQUENCE(COUNTA(A1:A32)),SORT(A1:A32,,-1)=x),COUNTIFS(A1:INDEX(A:A,ROW(x)),x))
))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for prompt response. System say "FILTER" function doesn't valid. @Harun24hr

Comment: @VidoRizkyP Then you are running on older version of Excel. What is your excel version?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Office Home and Student 2019 File-->Account. What should I do then? @Harun24hr

Comment: And I wanna convert it to spreadsheet. I hope I get help on it. Thanks @Harun24hr